# Proper use of preposition of

Tags: prepositions

According to the Oxford advance learner's  dictionary **risk** is often succeeded by **of**. But in the sentence

> Failure to take sustainable and urgent measures will inflict long-term harm on public health, affecting children even more by putting them at higher **risk for diseases**.

([source](https://www.thehindu.com/opinion/editorial/choked-by-smog/article25394644.ece))

'risk' is succeeded by for. Is this grammatically correct?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what your question is? I can't figure out what you're asking.

Comment: Technically speaking your example sentence is grammatically "valid", but in practice native speakers would almost always refer to ***risk of disease*** (note use of the singular, as well as the different preposition).

Answer (score -1):

@FumbleFingers is right: "of disease" would be preferred, though "for diseases" isn't too terribly unnatural. Just don't use "of disease**s**."